# MySQL Limit on the number of IF Statements in a single block?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm running into an odd issue with a trigger or stored procedure I'm writing (tried one, then tried the other, same problem).

I have a block of IF statements that check to determine if an incoming value is a set of digits, and then update a field accordingly:

Sanitized:

```
 IF(INC_Center = "001" OR INC_Center = "1") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place1";
 ELSEIF(INC_Center = "002" OR INC_Center = "2") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place2";
 ...
 ELSEIF(INC_Center = "101") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place45";
 ELSEIF(INC_Center = "101") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place46";
 ELSEIF(INC_Center = "103") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place47";
 ELSEIF(INC_Center = "104") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place48";
 ELSEIF(INC_Center = "110") THEN SET CenterAssigned = "Place49";
 ELSE SET CenterAssigned = "ERROR";
 END IF;
```

The downside to this is that there are 49 checks that have to occur. When I get to #45, I get a "parser stack overflow" from the MySQL Workbench (5.2.45 CE on Windows 8). I checked some other posts and saw that some recommended checking the thread_stack value, which mine was at the default of 192k, so I increased it to 256k, and no difference.

Is there a limit to the number of IF statements you can have on a MySQL block of code? The syntax looks right, and when I comment out the IF Statements past #45 they work fine, including the Else statement.

I could change it to a Case statement, it's just logic that has expanded as the number of locations has increased. But I'm curious if that's my problem.

Comment: This logic looks like a great opportunity to use a small table to me; what is a two-column table but a formalized CASE statement?

Comment: That's right, there are great opportunities to improve the design. However, I can not reproduce the problem, I tried with up to 500 ELSEIF and everything works as expected.

Comment: I ended up making the changes as Ollie Jones suggested, and have it perform a lookup. I wonder if it's a problem with how the MySQL Workbench builds the SQL statement from the GUI?